# How to switch between implementations of my SomethingManager class?

Tags: java, oop, spring, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I have an app which has OrgManager interface, which has a yet-to-be-built OrgManagerImpl

The OrgManagerImpl has to go and talk to some REST API 3rd party stuff which we don't have access to yet.

So while I am testing the web front end, I have written a mock OrgManagerImpl that implements the OrgManager, but at go-live I will need to swap that implementation over.

However now I am in the situation where I want to have the servlet select its OrgManager implementation dependent on some condition.

Also when I call myOrgManager.findCompany("SomeCompanyId") I want myOrgManager to go and look at all the possible implementations to find the company and make a big list.

Also I would like when I do myOrgManager.createCompany(company) to prefer one implementation over the others.

I seem to be heading towards a UserManagerManager object... but I feel that this is likely missing some point of Java or Object orientated design that I should know about.

Can anyone suggest a pattern, or strategy that I should be using instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Spring DI*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html) is very useful here.

You switch to other implementation just by changing xml

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring, then your implementation can be configured and injected. The runtime type (ie the implementation) can be changed easily.

Alternatively, if you're not using Spring, then you might want to look at some kind of factory pattern, where the factory decides which implementation to give you. Your factory could use some kind of external configuration (eg config file, environment variable etc) to decide on the implementation to use.